# Return a list of posts where Blog.ID == id in c#

Tags: c#, linq

This is what i have now.

```
    public ViewResult Index(string id)
    {
        var posts = db.Posts.Include(p => p.Blog.Id);
        return View(posts.ToList());
    }
```

this is returning all posts, how do i do the linq query to only give me postw with `Blog.id == id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just need to filter your posts with .Where(). Below, I'm assuming Blog.Id is a string. If not you'll have to cast appropriately.

```
public ViewResult Index(string id)
{
    var posts = db.Posts.Where(p => p.Blog.Id == id);
    return View(posts.ToList());
}
```